# Exception in thread Thread-5: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn

Recently I was evaluating a tflearn model using it's model.evaluate(test_X, test_y) method with the test data and there I am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vishwas.abhyankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/vishwas.abhyankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/vishwas.abhyankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "/Users/vishwas.abhyankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "/Users/vishwas.abhyankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 180, in slice_array
    return [x[start] for x in X]
  File "/Users/vishwas.abhyankar/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 180, in <listcomp>
    return [x[start] for x in X]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my original method:

```
def evaluate(self):
    return self.model.evaluate(self.test_x, self.test_y)
```

> here self.test_x was a list of lists like: [[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
>   and self.test_y was a list of lists like: [[0, 1], [1, 0]]

Modified fixed version of this methods:

```
def evaluate(self):
    return self.model.evaluate(np.array(self.test_x), np.array(self.test_y))
```

> Here I converted the lists into numpy arrays, and not model.evaluate(X, y) methods works fine.